Mergefield showing extra lines
I am using a software called Conga Composer that takes merge fields in a word document and populates the values.
As an example this is my merge field
{{TableStart:clause}}{{IF "{{QUOTECLAUSEASSOCIATION_PARAMETER_CLAUSE}}" = "760B" "{{HTML:QUOTECLAUSEASSOCIATION__CCLAUSE_TEXT_RICH}}" ""}}{{TableEnd:clause}} 

The problem is that {{QUOTECLAUSEASSOCIATION_PARAMETER_CLAUSE}} returns 32 values. So when it finally find 760B, it prints the false statements as blank lines.
So lets say as it compares the value, the 5th value is correct so it returns true.
it will have 4 blank lines on top and the remaining 27 false lines after as empty spaces.
Between each paragraphs I end up with so many blank lines.
How do i make sure there is no blank lines

According to the template syntax it looks like Conga Composer uses Aspose.Words and it's Mail Merge feature. If so, you can try using MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs and MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveContainingFields: https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.mailmerging/mailmergecleanupoptions/
